# Can Salesforce be used for multi user game type experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning

This is extremely generic question about Salesforce capability. Can I develop an application where same UI is being shared between several users?

Say for example I was building a card game, where a game starts and multiple user open and see the same page but with slightly different views?

On the server maybe I can save the state of the game with every move by every player and refresh each individual user’s view. I think there is something like subscribing to some events or something in Salesforce.

Not very experienced with Salesforce, so before I spend several weeks, I just wonder if it’s even possible.

Looking to build a planning poker type application.

Comment: It may be possible, but this strikes me as something Salesforce isn't really built to handle.  Salesforce itself isn't a "general computation" platform. Heroku (which was acquired by Salesforce some years ago) is a general computation platform. At any rate, I think this question is too broad for the Q&A format of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can build a user interface which is viewed and updated by many people with real time UI updates.

I would create a solution using the following metadata:

1. A few custom objects to store data about games, players, stories, and scores.
2. Platform events for the types of events which occur during a planning poker game such as the game beginning, a vote is cast, or a new player joins a game.
3. Triggers or Flows/Process Builders on the objects to publish Platform events when they are updated, inserted, or deleted.
4. Lightning Web Components to build the user interface. They will subscribe to the platform events and update the rendering of the UI accordingly.

Check out the documentation related to platform events and Lightning Web Components [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation).

As you can see, this would be a technically challenging, albeit fun to build.